# disable option using while

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code for disable the option if the value is equal in database. in my database i have 1:00 am, 1:30 am,2:00 am,2:30 am. but it only disable the 2:30 am what should i do i try this code but nothing happen?

```
     if(isset($_POST["doc"]))
$_SESSION["doc"] = $_GET["doc"];        
                  $dr=$_SESSION['doc'];
   $q = mysqli_query($link,"select * from doctor where DoctorName='". $dr ."'");
   $r =mysqli_fetch_Array($q);
$tf = $r["TimeFrom"];
         $tt = $r["TimeTo"];   


   ?>
     <?php
      if(isset($_POST["iDate"])){
           $st = "Pending";
    $app = "Approved";

       $qq2= mysqli_query($link,"select * from appointment where  Status='". $app ."' and PrefferedDate='". $date ."' and DoctorId='". $w."'");
     while($rrr = mysqli_fetch_array($qq2)){

    echo     $time=$rrr["PrefferedTime"];
     }
   ?>

  <tr><td>Time:<td><select name="time" class="form-control" id="time" required>
<option>  </option>
<?php

if($tf==1 && $tf<=$tt){
?>
<option value="1"
<?php
 if($time== "1:00 am "   ){
     echo "disabled";} else{
     echo "";}?>>1:00 am</option>
<?php
   $tf++;
 }
   ?>
<?php
if($tf==2 && $tf<=$tt){
?>
<option value="2"
<?php
 if($time== "1:30 am "  ){
     echo "disabled";} else{
     echo "";}?>>1:30 am</option>
<?php
   $tf++;
 }
  ?>
<?php
if($tf==3 && $tf<=$tt){
?>
<option value="3"
<?php
 if($time== "2:00 am "    ){
     echo "disabled";} else{
     echo "";}?>>2:00 am</option>
<?php
   $tf++;
 }
 ?>
<?php
if($tf==4 && $tf<=$tt){
?>
<option value="4"
<?php
 if($time== "2:30 am "){
     echo "disabled";} else{
     echo "";}?>>2:30 am</option>
<?php
   $tf++;
 }

?>
<?php
if($tf==5 && $tf<=$tt){
?>
<option value="5"
<?php
 if($time== "3:00 am " ){
     echo "disabled";} else{
     echo "";}?>>3:00 am</option>
<?php
   $tf++;
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Put your html code inside while loop brackets.

Comment: don't save your data like this. Use proper mysql datatypes. Don't do `select *`. Spell Preferred right.

Comment: Where is `$tf` and `$tt` coming from? Also you should be using prepared statements to help protect yourself from sql injection attacks.

Comment: i try to put the while in inside brackets but its same

Comment: $tf Time from and TT time To it came from database by specific user

Comment: Then you have to define the value of those two variables before you can use them. Example `$tf = $row['TimeFom']`

Comment: i already define that. and im using it and working my problem is in another table. i want to disable the value that present in my database

Comment: You don't show us where you defined it, so **we can only go on what we see here**. According to the code you pasted above those two variables are not defined. You have to help us or we can't help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is it what you looking for?

```
<?php

if (isset($_POST["iDate"])) {

    $st = "Pending";
    $app = "Approved";

    $taken = [];
    $query = mysqli_query($link, "select PrefferedTime from appointment where  Status='{$app}' and PrefferedDate='{$date}' and DoctorId='{$w}'");
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {
        $taken[] = $row["PrefferedTime"]; // collect all present values
    }

    function is_taken($appointment, $all) {
        return count(array_filter($all, function ($v) use ($appointment) {
            return trim($v) == trim($appointment);
        })) > 0;
    }

    $appointments = [];
    for ($i = 1; $i < 24 * 2 - 1; $i++)
        $appointments[$i] = date('g:i a', $start + ($i - 1) * (60 * 30));

    $options = [];
    foreach ($appointments as $id => $label) { // loop through all available
        if (($id >= $tf) && ($id <= $tt))
            $options[] = '<option value="' . $id . '" ' 
                         . (is_taken($label, $taken) ? 'disabled' : '') // disable if present in db
                         . '>' . $label . '</option>';
    }

?>

    <tr><td>Time:<td><select name="time" class="form-control" id="time" required>
        <option>  </option>
        <?php echo join(PHP_EOL . "\t", $options); //output all options, taken - grayed ?>
    </select>

<?php

}

?>
```

Comment: the option value is dynamic i edit my post.  thankyou btw

Comment: i include there where i get the value of tf and tt

Comment: @ShermaineChaingan, updated my post. Now it should output only options from `TimeFrom` to `TimeTo`, already present in db records will be disabled

Comment: what if the doctor is from 1 am up to 3 am every doctor have different schedule what should i do ?

Comment: thats why i get the value of the doctor table his timefrom and timeto

Comment: as i said, i already updated my answer. this `($id >= $tf) && ($id <= $tt)` portion of code will ensure, that only hours from `$tf` to `$tt` will be shown in select-box

Comment: $appointments = [1 => '1:00 am', 2 => '1:30 am', 3 => '2:00 am', 4 => '2:30 am', 5 => '3:00 am']; what is tthe function of this ?

Comment: i use your code but all the availability of doctor is not showing :(

Comment: in what format `TimeFrom` and `TimeTo` is saved? as hours, as minutes, as string like `1:30 am`?

Comment: as a number.   example The time from is 1 its value is 1:00 am thats why i use this code <?php
if($tf==1 && $tf<=$tt){
?>
<option value="1"
<?php
 if($time== "1:00 am " || $timee== "1:00 am "   || $time== "1:00 am " || $ti== "1:00 am "  ){
  echo "disabled";} else{
  echo "";}?>>1:00 am</option>
<?php
   $tf++;
 }
   ?>

Comment: i've updated code (added debug line `var_dump(['tf' => $tf, 'tt' => $tt, 'taken' => $taken, 'options' => $options]);`). try to use it and show what it prints

Comment: also, maybe we should move to proposed chat?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/89439/discussion-between-shermaine-chaingan-and-ankhzet).